# Kafka Streams latency with complex topology

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I'm working on a solution for a real-time processing use case. The current implementation involves two different Kafka Streams applications and a middle Kafka topic. I'm using [Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Streams Binder](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/3.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_kafka_streams_binder) and the [DSL](https://kafka.apache.org/27/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html).

```
input-topics --> [PRE-PROCESSOR] --> middle-topic --> [PROCESSOR] --> output-topic
```

Despite the simple code, the generated topology for the first application is rather complex since it uses a [foreign-key KTable-Ktable join](https://kafka.apache.org/27/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#ktable-ktable-fk-join). The second application is non-trivial too, handling different use-cases and tombstones generation. Each topology has ~20 processing nodes and ~3/4 materialized state stores.

The solution is fully functional but doesn't perform very well in my opinion: the main concern is about ***latency***. The application doesn't (yet) any significant computation to be responsible for the processing slowdown. Tinkering with different configurations as suggested [here](https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/client-apps/optimizing/latency.html) (mainly `linger.ms` for kafka streams producers) has improved the situation but even at a very low load (10 messages/second), we observe an end-to-end value of ~400ms, with spikes of 800/1200ms for the first result in the batch. At higher load (20-30 messages/second), the solution simply strives to catch up with high CPU processing and broker load (hence a ***throughput*** issue).

Is this the expected result for a non-trivial Kafka Stream application or I'm missing something? I understand that the middle topic and the internal repartitioning topic generated by the DSL lead to a producer-topic-consumer chain and a detrimental effect, but I was expecting something in the range of 50-100ms on low load for a [millisecond processing latency](https://kafka.apache.org/27/documentation/streams/core-concepts) library.

Thank You

Comment: Please check the value of cache.max.bytes.buffering, commit.interval.ms config

Comment: Already tried even with *development* settings such as `0`, now using for the test something like the defaults:
`commit.interval.ms=100
cache.max.bytes.buffering=5242880`